# geoDjango changing longitude automatically

Tags: django, postgresql, geolocation, postgis, geodjango

i'm making a location base web application  and for this i'm using geoDjango and postgis . the problem is whenever i try to store some location(latitude/longitude) around dhaka,bangladesh ,it automatically  change the longitude. after doing some debugging i found that, whenever  longitude cross 90.00, geoDjango save longitude as 89.something .

My model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as locationModels

class Advertise(models.Model):
        house_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        geoLocation = locationModels.PointField(geography=True, null=True)
```

Example:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
lat, lng = 23.724609, 88.882694
pnt = Point(lat, lng)
add = models.Advertise(geoLocation=pnt,house_name='test1')
add.save()

add = models.Advertise.objects.filter(house_name='test1')
```

Output of `add[0].geoLocation.y` is `88.882694`

if i change the value of `lat,lng` to `23.777976, 90.010106`, the Output of `add[0].geoLocation.y` became `89.989894`, but it should be `90.010106`

can anyone tell me where i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are swapping latitudes and longitudes. You must specify the longitude first (x), then the latitude (y).

Unfortunately, instead of throwing an error, PostGIS will try to interpret the out of bound value, like moving on the other side of earth or moving "back" from the pole if the latitude is > 90 degrees.